# Logic issue in minesweeper

Tags: javascript, jquery

--SOLVED--

### I was just forgetting to reset the number of flags after each game.

I'm having issues with the number of flags in my minesweeper game. For some reason, sometimes when I flag a tile the number of flags increases by more than 1. Sometimes it increases by 3, sometimes 4, sometimes 7. I can't find the issue in my logic, so I was hoping to get another set of eyes on it.

The only sort of pattern I can see when it adds more flags than it should, i.e. the `flags` variable is incremented more than once, is when I flag a tile that is mostly surrounded by revealed tiles.

Javascript:

```
var flags = 0;
var trueFlags = 0;

function newGame() {
    var cols = $("#width").val();
    var rows = $("#height").val();

    if (cols < 8 || rows < 8) {
        return;
    }else if (cols > 40 || rows > 30) {
        return;
    }
    boardClear();
    possibleBombs = (rows * cols) - 1;
    numBombs = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
            if (numBombs < possibleBombs) {
                var q = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
                if (0 <= q && q <= 2) {
                    numBombs += 1;
                    $("#board").append('<button type="button" class="tile" data-row = ' + i + ' data-col = ' + j + ' data-contains = ' + 0 + ' data-flagged = ' + false + '></button>').prop("revealed", false);
                }
                else {
                    $("#board").append('<button type="button" class="tile" data-row = ' + i + ' data-col = ' + j + ' data-contains = ' + 1 + 'data-flagged = ' + false + '></button>').prop("revealed", false);
                }
            } 
            else {
                $("#board").append('<button type="button" class="tile" data-row = ' + i + ' data-col = ' + j + ' data-contains = ' + 1 + ' data-flagged = ' + false + '></button>').prop("revealed", false);
            }
        }
        $("#board").append("<br/>");
    }
    $(".controls h2").text("Bombs to go: " + numBombs);
    $(".tile").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".tile").width(15);
    $(".tile").height(15);
    console.log("bombs: " + numBombs, "possible: " + possibleBombs);

    $(".tile").click(function(e) {
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            flagKey($(this));
            $(".controls h2").text("Bombs to go: " + (numBombs - flags));
        }
        else if ($(this).data("contains") == 0) {
            console.log("you lose");
            boardClear();
            newGame();
            return;
        }   
        else {
            revealNeighbors($(this));
            // if (gameWon() == true) {
            //     alert("You have won!");
            //     newGame();
            // }
            return;
        }
    });
}

function boardClear() {
    $("#board").empty();
}

function revealNeighbors(tile) {
    var cordsx = tile.data("row");
    var cordsy = tile.data("col");

    // tile has bomb
    if(tile.data("contains") == 0) {return;}
    // tile is flagged
    else if(tile.data("flagged") == true){return;}
    // tile has been revealead already
    else if(tile.prop("revealed") == true) {return;}

    // reveal the tile
    var tileBombs = nearbyBombCount(tile);
    tile.prop("revealed", true);
    tile.text(tileBombs);
    tile.css("background-color", "grey");

    if (tileBombs == 0){tile.text("");}
    else if(tileBombs != 0) {return;}

    for (var i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
        for (var j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
            if (cordsx + i < 1 || cordsy + j < 1) {continue;}
            else if (cordsx + i > $("#width").val() || cordsy + j > $("#height").val()) {continue;}
            else if (i == 0 && j == 0) {continue;}
            var neighbor = $('.tile[data-row="' + (cordsx+i) + '"][data-col ="'+(cordsy+j)+'"]');
            revealNeighbors(neighbor);
        }
    }
}

function nearbyBombCount(tile) {
    var cx = tile.data("row");
    var cy = tile.data("col");
    var nearbyBombs = 0;
    for (var n = -1; n < 2; n++) {
        for (var m = -1; m < 2; m++) {
            if (cx + n < 1 || cy + m < 1) {continue;}
            else if (cx + n > $("#width").val() || cy + m > $("#height").val()) {continue;}
            var neighbor = $('.tile[data-row="' + (cx+n) + '"][data-col ="'+(cy+m)+'"]');
            if (neighbor.data("contains") == 0) {
                nearbyBombs++;
            }
        }
    }
    return nearbyBombs;
}

function flagKey(tile) {
    // tile is already revealed
    if (tile.data("revealed") == true) {
        return;
    }
    // tile is already flagged
    else if (tile.data("flagged") == true) {
        tile.data("flagged", false);
        tile.css("background-color", "white");
        flags--;
        // contains bomb
        if (tile.data("contains") == 0) {
            trueFlags--;
        }
        return;
    }
    // tile not flagged
    else if (tile.data("flagged") == false) {
        flags++;
        tile.data("flagged", true);
        tile.css("background-color", "red");
        // contains bomb
        if (tile.data("contains") == 0) {
            trueFlags++;
            console.log(trueFlags);
        }
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

My guess is that there's something wrong with my `revealNeighbors()` function or it's some scope issue, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

Comment: Are you certain of those amounts you claim the var is being modified by? How do you check that?
Also, are you certain the flagKey function is onlye being called once?

Comment: @Fefee.33 I am certain that it is sometimes being changed by different amounts. I am debugging through `console.log()`. I am also certain that the function is only being called once for the same reason.

Comment: @Fefee.33 I'm just dumb. I'm forgetting to reset the number of flags between games.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I change a litle and works fine

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .tile{padding:5px;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
   Width : <input type="text" id="width" value="15" /> Height :<input type="text"  id="height" value="15" /><input type="button" onclick="newGame()" id="btnstart" value="start" />
    <br />
    <div>
        <div id="board" >

        </div>
    </div>
<script>
var flags = 0;
var trueFlags = 0;

function newGame() {
    var cols = $("#width").val();
    var rows = $("#height").val();
   
    if (cols < 8 || rows < 8) {
        return;
    }else if (cols > 40 || rows > 30) {
        return;
    }
    boardClear();
    possibleBombs = (rows * cols) - 1;
    numBombs = 0;
    
    for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
            if (numBombs < possibleBombs) {
                var q = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
                
                if (q <= 2) {
                   
                    numBombs += 1;
                    $("#board").append('<button type="button" class="tile" data-row = ' + i + ' data-col = ' + j + ' data-contains = ' + 0 + ' data-flagged = ' + false + '></button>').prop("revealed", false);
                }
                else {
                    $("#board").append('<button type="button" class="tile" data-row = ' + i + ' data-col = ' + j + ' data-contains = ' + 1 + 'data-flagged = ' + false + '></button>').prop("revealed", false);
                }
            } 
            else {
                $("#board").append('<button type="button" class="tile" data-row = ' + i + ' data-col = ' + j + ' data-contains = ' + 1 + ' data-flagged = ' + false + '></button>').prop("revealed", false);
            }
        }
        $("#board").append("<br/>");
    }
    $(".controls h2").text("Bombs to go: " + numBombs);
    $(".tile").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".tile").width(15);
    $(".tile").height(15);
    console.log("bombs: " + numBombs, "possible: " + possibleBombs);

    $(".tile").click(function (e) {
        
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            flagKey($(this));
            $(".controls h2").text("Bombs to go: " + (numBombs - flags));
        }
        else if ($(this).data("contains") == 0) {
            console.log("you lose");
            boardClear();
            newGame();
            return;
        }   
        else {
            revealNeighbors($(this));
            // if (gameWon() == true) {
            //     alert("You have won!");
            //     newGame();
            // }
            return;
        }
    });
}

function boardClear() {
    $("#board").empty();
}

function revealNeighbors(tile) {
    var cordsx = tile.data("row");
    var cordsy = tile.data("col");

    // tile has bomb
    if(tile.data("contains") == 0) {return;}
    // tile is flagged
    else if(tile.data("flagged") == true){return;}
    // tile has been revealead already
    else if(tile.prop("revealed") == true) {return;}

    // reveal the tile
    var tileBombs = nearbyBombCount(tile);
    tile.prop("revealed", true);
    tile.text(tileBombs);
    tile.css("background-color", "grey");

    if (tileBombs == 0){tile.text("");}
    else if(tileBombs != 0) {return;}

    for (var i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
        for (var j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
            if (cordsx + i < 1 || cordsy + j < 1) {continue;}
            else if (cordsx + i > $("#width").val() || cordsy + j > $("#height").val()) {continue;}
            else if (i == 0 && j == 0) {continue;}
            var neighbor = $('.tile[data-row="' + (cordsx+i) + '"][data-col ="'+(cordsy+j)+'"]');
            revealNeighbors(neighbor);
        }
    }
}

function nearbyBombCount(tile) {
    var cx = tile.data("row");
    var cy = tile.data("col");
    var nearbyBombs = 0;
    for (var n = -1; n < 2; n++) {
        for (var m = -1; m < 2; m++) {
            if (cx + n < 1 || cy + m < 1) {continue;}
            else if (cx + n > $("#width").val() || cy + m > $("#height").val()) {continue;}
            var neighbor = $('.tile[data-row="' + (cx+n) + '"][data-col ="'+(cy+m)+'"]');
            if (neighbor.data("contains") == 0) {
                nearbyBombs++;
            }
        }
    }
    return nearbyBombs;
}

function flagKey(tile) {
    // tile is already revealed
    if (tile.data("revealed") == true) {
        return;
    }
    // tile is already flagged
    else if (tile.data("flagged") == true) {
        tile.data("flagged", false);
        tile.css("background-color", "white");
        flags--;
        // contains bomb
        if (tile.data("contains") == 0) {
            trueFlags--;
        }
        return;
    }
    // tile not flagged
    else if (tile.data("flagged") == false) {
        flags++;
        tile.data("flagged", true);
        tile.css("background-color", "red");
        // contains bomb
        if (tile.data("contains") == 0) {
            trueFlags++;
            console.log(trueFlags);
        }
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```